# Perl OR do multiple things

Tags: perl

I was working on something and a bit ago I could have swore that this was a valid thing you could do, but today I was googling and I couldn't find any kind of reference.

```
$StaementHandler->execute($val1, $val2, $val3) or {
    SomeFunction($var1, $var2);
    Setup::Abend("Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr");
}
```

So I was wondering if there was a special way you could run several things instead of just die.

Also if not, I just wanted to make sure this would produce the equivalent result.

```
unless ($StaementHandler->execute($val1, $val2, $val3)) {
    SomeFunction($var1, $var2);
    Setup::Abend("Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `or do {...}`.  `or` can only handle single-statement expressions, and `do` takes a block and turns it into a single-statement expression (from the perspective of outside the braces).

And, personally, I think the second option is generally (but not always) more readable anyway.

Comment: Thanks, because I felt like I was crazy today, because all of the or documentation didn't have an example and I was so sure that it was something I could do. *Pun intended* EDIT:  Ironically I had the right sentax in the question tittle.

Comment: I find the term "single-statement expressions" confusing; I would prefer just "single expressions".  statements are a superset of expressions, and it definitely can't handle statements that aren't expressions.